# How to know if ZEO is packing or not?

Tags: plone

What kind of indicators there are to watch if ZEO is currently packing Data.fs and has operation been succeful (this far)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The presence of a Data.fs.pack file in var/filestorage indicates packing. If it's size isn't static, the operation is continuing. When packing is completed, this file will become the main Data.fs file and the old one will become Data.fs.old.

You may also check the zeoserver.log file (typically at var/zeoserver/zeoserver.log), where you'll find notifications like:

```
2012-12-23T13:50:03 (127.0.0.1:39920) pack(time=1356213003.545583) started...
2012-12-23T13:50:34 (127.0.0.1:39920) pack(time=1356213003.545583) complete
```